# jquery: selectbox with different output on different selections

Tags: php, jquery, date

I'm trying to get input box to show different dates depending on the users selection from select box. If user select today today date should show if tomorrow, the date for tomorrow.

My question is how do I get the select box to show the correct date?

```
<?php 
$tomorrow  = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+2, date("Y")));
$today = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d"), date("Y")));
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#select-bil").change(function () {
<?php                                 
echo      'var datum = "'.$tomorrow.'";'
?>    
        var str ="";
        $("#select-bil option:selected").each(function () {
          });
      $("input[name$='div-one']").val(datum);
    })
    .change();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not entirely sure what you're trying to do, try this though

```
<?php
$tomorrow  = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+1, date("Y")));
$today = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")));
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    <?php
        echo 'var tomorrow = "'.$tomorrow.'";';
        echo 'var today = "'.$today.'";';
    ?>
    $("#select-bil>option:contains('today')").val(today);
    $("#select-bil>option:contains('tomorrow')").val(tomorrow);

    $("#select-bil").change(function () {
        $("input[name$='div-one']").val($("#select-bil option:selected").val());
    }).change();
});
</script>
<input name="div-one" />
<select id="select-bil">
 <option value="today">today</option>
 <option value="tomorrow">tomorrow</option>
 <option value="some other day">some other day</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it’s as easy as

```
$('#select-option-for-today').val ('<?= $today ?>')
$('#select-option-for-tomororrow').val ('<?= $tomorrow ?>')
```

(If `<?=` doesn’t work in your config, try to `<?php` echo the same)